# htaccess redirect parked domains and main domain to different wordpress folders

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, dns, subdirectory

This might sound a little confusing but I have 3 Domain names one main domain and 2 parked domains.

```
www.main1.com
www.parked1.com
www.parked2.com
```

I have 3 wordpress installed inside `www` folder :

```
www.main1.com/site1
www.main1.com/site2
www.main1.com/site3
```

I want to browse them as fallows:

```
   www.main1.com   >> www.main1.com/site1 
   www.parked1.com >> www.main1.com/site2
   www.parked2.com >> www.main1.com/site3
```

I have managed to do the first one **`www.main1.com   >> www.main1.com/site1`** by following the tutorials "Giving WordPress Its Own Directory" on worpress.org

I have copied the index.php and .htaccess files from the wordpress folder to the www folder but only the main domain name worked.

Please Help me to solve this. Is it even possible?

Kind Regards

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Yeh... & what difference with it make? thnks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use addon domain instead of subdomain. See the following link for the differences. 
http://webnet77.com/webstuff/parked-add-on-domain.html